# Swear followed by the infinitive and gerund

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

**I swear to do it tomorrow!** is standard.

What about the prefect infinitive and gerunds?

1 I swear to have done it yesterday! - CORRECT?

2 I swear doing it yesterday! - CORRECT?

3 I swear having done it yesterday! - CORRECT?

Answer (score 4):

swear is basically a performative verb. That page explains them in more detail.
[performative verbs in the form of a declaration](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Performative#:%7E:text=Performative%20Verbs,-The%20type%20of&text=Examples%20are%3A%20promise%2C%20name%2C,%2C%20insist%2C%20declare%20or%20refuse.)

More idiomatic for this performative meaning:

- I swear I *will do it* tomorrow. [I raise my hand]
- I swear *I did it* yesterday. [I raise my hand]
- I swear (to you) that I have done it in the past. [undefined past, not performative]

The three samples in the question are basically ungrammatical.

"swear to" can be followed by a noun/pronoun:

I swore *to him* that I had done that.

**OR, with a verb after to**

- I swear to leave within the hour. [present]
- I swore to leave within the hour. [past, no change after to]

No past infinitive after to:
**I swore to having left** at 6 o'clock. [no past infinitive]
**I will swear to having left** at 6 o'clock.

Comment: If they are ungrammatical how can you explain these examples taken from different books? 1 Will you swear to have seen one gun? 2 Do you swear doing any work for Charles? 3 This concession was not pursued on redirect examination and , accordingly , the record was left with testimony by a witness about an event which had assertedly preceded execution of a contract that he could not swear having seen. Are they also ungrammatical?

Comment: @user1425 You are now changing course. The ones in your question do not work.  You can't expect me to cover every single instance. That said, Your 1) there is similar to my last one. I do not accept 2) or 3) Do you swear ***to* doing any work for Charles**. 3) that he could not swear **to having seen**.

Comment: @user1425 Some of those sentences use a different meaning of *to swear*.   "I swear to avenge my brother" means "I promise that I will avenge my brother", but "I will swear to have seen one gun" means "I will say in court that I definitely saw one gun".

Comment: If you mean that 1 Will you swear to have seen one gun? is similar to "I will swear to having left at 6 o'clock." then they are critically different. The first one employs the infinitive, yours employs the gerund.

Comment: stangdon, how are they different? Can you refer to a dictionary's entries which would differentiate between the two? "I will swear to have seen one gun" - what inhibits one from interpreting it as "I promise to say in court that I definitely saw one gun". But even if they were different (which I doubt yet) would that mean that they are used differently in terms of grammar?

Comment: I don't understand how this sentence works "Will you swear to have seen one gun?" but this doesn't " I swear to have done it yesterday!" They are the same in terms of syntax.

Comment: @user1425 I am looking for a good dictionary reference, but "swear to (bare infinitive of verb)" is just a different usage from "swear to (a fact as expressed as a noun clause)".  I don't actually like the sentence "I will swear to have seen one gun", because it should really be "I will swear to **having** seen one gun" - note that that *having* is a gerund.  You also just have to use some common sense.  How can you promise that you will do something that is already in the past?

Comment: "to have seen" is not in the past. It's the same as "I know her to have been a good wife". By the same token, I swear to have seen MEANS or SHOULD MEAN I swear that I saw. Maybe it's a bit outdated English.

Comment: @user1425 I swear [something] is a performative verb: I swear I will do it. I swear I have done it. It's raising your hand in a declarative statement. It's similar to promise, same thing. **To swear to something is not performative**. So, you can say: Will you swear to having seen a gun? Or: Will you swear to seeing a gun. Versus: I swear I saw it yesterday (performative). The difference is performative versus non-performative. "swear to something" is asking a person if they will state it as a performative.

Comment: "I know her to have been a good wife" is past tense. To wit, "I know her to have been a good wife but she isn't one any longer." Generally we say: I swear I saw him or I swear I have seen him before (performatives). And I will swear to that in court. [not performative]. to have seen is also past tense.

Comment: From the standpoint of a learner, of one of which I am, the distinction you draw between "swear" being performative or not, has little practical value. It even complicates things, but I see what you mean. "I know her to have been a good wife" is never past tense. It's the present simple "I know" while "to have been" is not a tense, it's a form of the infinitive.

Comment: @user1425 Unfortunately, you are mistaken. I know her [in the present, I have that knowledge] **to have been a good wife** [**in the past**].  I know her to **be a good wife** = Present Tense. It is very difficult to help someone who seems not to want to accept an obvious statement. How you claim that "to have been x" is not past tense, is beyond me. I even gave you a sentence contrasting to have been and is no longer.

Comment: You don't differentiate between tenses and the forms of infinitive. If "to have been" is a tense, then reveal the name of this tense. There is no past tense. The past tense is a category which consists of 4 tenses, namely, the past simple, past continuous, past perfect, past perfect continuous. Which one of them is "to have been"? None. Don't feel ashamed if you have learnt something new from a learner.

Comment: @user1425 to have gone, to have been, to have seen are **perfect infinitives** and the meaning refers to the past, not the present. And here's Cambridge grammar: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked I said past tense, big deal. The meaning is about the past.

Comment: But you said they were tenses.

Comment: I have spotted another mistake in your explanation. "Past infinitive after to: I swore to having left" - having left is not an infinitive.

Comment: @user1425 Yes, it should say no past infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different meanings of *swear*, that subcategorize for different grammatical arguments.

*Swear* meaning "strongly promise" takes either a *to* infinitive clause, or a finite *that* clause with explicit expression of intention:

> I swear to give up smoking = I swear that I will give up smoking.

*Swear* meaning "strongly assert or affirm" normally takes a finite *that* clause, but can also take *to* with an *-ing* clause. The latter is rather literary or old-fashioned.

Your sample sentence has the first meaning, and so is as you say standard with the *to* infinitive.

Your three numbered sentences are all in the past, so cannot have the first meaning, and must have the second. None of them satisfy the conditions I've mentioned above, so all three are ungrammatical.

Comment: Upvoted. But still I think they are not ungrammatical as such but they represent older English. After all, I didn't make them up but copied from books.

Comment: The Cretan , then , claims to have met a man who swears to have seen and helped Odysseus recently

Comment: I won't argue that, @user1425. I was wondering whether to describe them as _ungrammatical_ or merely _unidiomatic_.